# ng-options only shows last value of array repeatedly in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in select dropedown ng-options only shows last value of array repeatedly in IE but in other browser it shows perfectly.

here is my code,

```
 <select  ng-model="selectedSeries" ng-options="carline as carline.carSeries for carline in requestSeries" ng-change="changeseries()">
```

and the angular script,

```
$scope.requestSeries = seriesarray;
/* this is the console value of seriesarray*/   

 console.log(JSON.stringify(seriesarray));
      $scope.requestSeries = [{"carSeries":"C117-CLA Coupe"},{"carSeries":"C156-GLA"},{"carSeries":"C177-A Klasse"},{"carSeries":"C190-AMG GT"},{"carSeries":"C204-C Klasse"},{"carSeries":"C205-C Klasse"},{"carSeries":"C293-EVA 1"}];
```

Result in IE looks like
    [dropedowninIE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsnlN.jpg)
and result in other browser looks perfect
[dropedownin chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwXRL.png)

Comment: Check this site http://www.programering.com/a/MTNzYDMwATU.html

Comment: <select novalidate="" ng-model="selectedSeries" ng-options="carline.carSeries for carline in requestSeries"></select>

Comment: I used following way and abdul it is working

Comment: Review plunkr in IE http://plnkr.co/edit/7OIk31C6UiJoucimoLsa?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for ur comments!! it works only if i give  [{"carSeries":"C117-CLA Coupe"},{"carSeries":"C156-GLA"}... hardcode, but im genearting this json dynamically in that case its not working